# How to get object value in void method SUT Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

i'm looking for a way to get the value of a List in my Test, i have this structure in my SUT:

```
.//... A run method with logic that call this:
 private void buys(){
     List<GroupLin> gruposByEarly = this.earlys.stream().map(this::agruparCompras).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<MyClass> toSave = gruposByEarly.stream().flatMap(this::getToSave).map(this::valorar).collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.writer.persist(toSave.stream());
}
```

And i have a test with some like this:

```
@Test
public void runTest() {
 //...when sentences 
    super.cvlTask.run(getStepRequest());
 //...asserts
}
```

But i don't know how see the 'List toSave' object, i tried with this:

```
 when(entityWriter.persist(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(aMethodThatCallSUTGetMethodOfList);
```

But things like that don't work, any idea because the when run before the logic in my SUT and i tried with @Spy but it has the same problem

I did this too:

```
private List<ValoracionLin> toSave;
//...logic
//... A run method with logic that call this:
 private void buys(){
     List<GroupLin> gruposByEarly = this.earlys.stream().map(this::agruparCompras).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.toSave = gruposByEarly.stream().flatMap(this::getToSave).map(this::valorar).collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.writer.persist(toSave.stream());
}

public List<MyClass> getToSave(){
   return this.toSave;
}
```

And in my test:

```
 when(entityWriter.persist(Mockito.any())) 
.thenReturn(getValoracionesResultadoSUT());

 private Integer getValoracionesResultadoSUT() {
       this.valoracionesResultado = this.cvlTask.getToSave();
       if(null!=this.valoracionesResultado)
       return this.valoracionesResultado.size();
       else 
       return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Far better to use an ArgumentCaptor than to declare toSave as an additional name you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what you do is

```
@Mock Writer writer;

@InjectMock MyService sut;

@Captor ArgumentCaptor<List<Data>> captor;

@Test
public void testSave() {
    List<InputData> input = ...
    sut.callMethod(input);

    // check that write() was called on the writer
    verify(writer).write(captor.capture());
    // retrieve the value it was called with
    List<Data> saved = captor.getValue();
    // do some more validation on the data if necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `toSave` variable is declared local to the `buys()` method, so it disappears as soon as that method finishes. You should declare `toSave` as a private instance variable of the class that contains the `buys()` method, and then add a public getter to return that reference.

Comment: I did that, but don't work beacuse to call that get method i use when(....).then(icallGetMethod) but the "when" run before that the test

Comment: It works now, the problem was the orden in my structure, i didn't use "when", just the consult, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the List "toSave" outside of the method (declare it as a class variable, not as a method variable), and then use a getter to retrieve it.

Comment: I did that, but don't work beacuse to call that get method i use when(....).then(icallGetMethod) but the "when" run before that the test

Comment: @jaxonjma What error are you recieving and in which line?

Comment: it is null always in the example, because the when run before my test...

Comment: it runs when(entityWriter.persist(Mockito.any()) before that my call to SUT

Comment: It works now, the problem was the orden in my structure, i didn't use "when", just the consult, thank you.